# Permutations on Array Elements (With Restrictions)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

This question is as follows:

"Let $K$ be an integer satisfying $1 \leq K \leq N$. In how many ways can we arrange the $N$ objects in $B$ so that $B_K$ is smaller than all the objects that follow it in $B$ (i.e., $B_K < B_I$ for all subscripts $I$ greater than $K$)? Answer the question for $N = 6$, $K = 4$ first. Then give the answer for general $N$ and $K$. Simplify your answer algebraically as much as possible."

My thought process and answer:

We have an array 6 elements long: `[][][][][][]`
(1) We need to place $3$ elements in the last positions so that the last $2$ are larger than the element in $4$th cell.  One element automatically goes in position $4$, so we don't need to calculate that, but (2) we need to arrange the elements in positions $5$ and $6$. (3) We now need to arrange the first $3$ elements.

(1) $6C3 \times$

(2) $2! \times$

(3) $3! = 240$

or

(1) $n C (n - k + 1) \times$

(2) $(n - k)! \times$

(3) $(n - k + 1)!$

My formula is derived from the items in the parenthesis above:

$$\frac{n!(n-k)!(n - k + 1)!}{(n-k+1)!\bigl(n-(n-k+1)\bigr)!}$$

and I reduced it down to:

$$\frac{n!(n-k)!}{(k-1)!}$$

Although, I can't tell if it can be reduced anymore.  I also am not confident at all in my numerical answer.

Comment: Please pardon my lack of MathJax, I'm attempting to learn it now and will try to format this question after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer for the case $N = 6$, $K = 4$ is correct.

Your answer for the general case is not.  Consider $n = 7$ and $k = 2$.  Your formula 
$$\frac{n!(n - k)!}{(k - 1)!}$$
yields
$$\frac{7!5!}{1!} = 7!5! > 7!$$
which is impossible there are $7!$ ways to arrange $7$ objects without restrictions.  The reason is that your factor of $(n - k + 1)!$ is incorrect since only $k - 1$ objects appear before the $k$th object.

We can choose which $k - 1$ objects appear before the $k$th position in $\binom{n}{k - 1}$ ways, permute them in $(k - 1)!$ ways, and permute the $n - k$ objects that appear after the $k$th position in $(n - k)!$ ways.  Hence, the number of permissible arrangements 
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k - 1}(k - 1)!(n - k)! & = \frac{n!}{(k - 1)![n - (k - 1)]!}(k - 1)!(n - k)!\\ 
& = \frac{n!}{(k - 1)!(n - k + 1)!}(k - 1)!(n - k)!\\ 
& = \frac{n!}{n - k + 1}
\end{align*}

Alternatively, we can select which $n - (k - 1) = n - k + 1$ objects which appear in the last $n - (k - 1)$ positions in $\binom{n}{n - k + 1}$ ways, permute the $n - k$ objects after the $k$th position in $(n - k)!$ ways, and permute the first $k - 1$ objects in $(k - 1)!$ ways.  Hence, the number of permissible arrangements is 
$$\binom{n}{n - k + 1}(n - k)!(k - 1)! = \frac{n!}{(n - k + 1)!(k - 1)!}(n - k)!(k - 1)! = \frac{n!}{n - k + 1}$$

Comment: So my route was more closely related to your second version.  Everything makes total sense, but one part.  My problem is incorrect with the factor of `(n - k + 1)`, but you simply used `(k - 1)`.  I understand that mine is only correct for this specific case and yours is correct for all cases, but how did you know to use `k - 1`?  Is it because `k` is the "partitioning element?" and you needed to derive the number of elements before it through it alone and not with `n`?  I know that `(n - k + 1)` is incorrect, as it fails for other examples, but I can't figure out why logically it can't work.

Comment: Once we choose the final $n - (k - 1) = n - k + 1$ elements, there is only one way to choose the smallest of them to be in the $k$th position.  It is now fixed, so we are only free to permute the $n - k$ elements that appear after it and the $k - 1$ elements that appear before it, which we can do in $(k - 1)!(n - k)!$ ways.  Your factor of $(n - k)!$ accounts for permutations of the elements that appear after the $k$th element.  Your factor of $(n - k + 1)!$ counts permutations of the $k$th element and those after it, but we have already counted permissible permutations of those elements.

Comment: This makes total sense.  Thanks a ton @N.F. Taussig, you've helped me multiple times already this semester.  Appreciate it greatly.